# Delete users who havent logged in for x days

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

got the simple code below

```
USERS=`cat /etc/passwd`
for USER in $USERS
do
   echo "---------- $USER --------------"
   last -n 4 $USER
done
```

I want to ideally remove all users who haven't logged in for over 60 days.

But the problem with reading the `/etc/passwd` is that i get all of the system users as well.

Any ideas how to get just the user created accounts and remove them is they havent logged in for 90 days.

Cheers

Comment: If you are that concerned about active accounts, maintain your own database of users that are eligible for auto-deletion instead of relying on `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Check `chage`. With `chage -l user` you can info and with `chage --something` make users disable after XX days.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the UID is between `UID_MIN` and `UID_MAX` (defined in `/etc/login.defs`):

```
UID_MIN=$(awk '/^UID_MIN/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)
UID_MAX=$(awk '/^UID_MAX/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)

USERS=$(awk -F: -v min=$UID_MIN -v max=$UID_MAX '{
  if ($3 >= min && $3 <= max) print $1
}' /etc/passwd)

now=$(date +%s)

for user in $USERS; do
  last_login=$(date -d "$(last -FRn 1 $user |
    egrep -v "wtmp begins|still logged in" |
    awk '{print $10 " " $11 " " $13 " " $12}')" +%s)
  [ $(( (now - last_login) / 86400 )) -ge 90 ] && echo $user
done
```

Comment: All this does it list users? And for me it's listing the root user over and over again. Ideally i would like a shell script that i can add to cron which checks if a user has logged in within x days... if not delete them.

Comment: Yes, all this does is list users. I don't recommend automatic deletion of user accounts. The reason why it was listing `root` over and over again was, because the part I had copy/pasted from your initial script echoed `$USER` (environment variable with the username of the currently logged-in user) instead of the loop variable `$user`. Variable names are case-sensitive. I updated my sample code so it prints only users that haven't logged in for 90 days or more.

Comment: @ubuntu101010101 If you really do want to delete them automatically, you can simply change the `echo` command at the end to a `deluser --remove-home` command.

Answer (score 0):

Check the home directory of the user (6th column) and ignore those that are empty.

Comment: that will not work since service-users like `named` or `lp` have entries there and you do not want to delete them.